# Identify this Indian comics with two protagonist fight with supernatural beings

Tags: story-identification, comics

In my childhood, more then 14 years ago. I used to read a Indian comic book with two charter as protagonist one with magical beard which changes length as per his wish and the second one who has a magical stick/wand. They mostly fight with ghosts, supernatural beings etc. In one of the storyline the man with beard use his beard to check if their is any danger present in the cave or not so that they can go through it and his beard come us with talking skull. In the same storyline the man with magical stick/wand lost his wand. Please help to identify this Indian comics book. I read it in Hindi.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The characters are

1. Taao JI with magical stick and
2. Rumjhum with magical beard...Usman Ali Khan

http://indiacomic.blogspot.in/

[image]